# Can't get max id from table in mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I want to get the maximum id number from MySQL Table I wrote that:

```
<?php
$servername='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='';
$databasename='myDB';
$con = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$databasename);
$max_id= $con->query('SELECT max(id) from myTable');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($max_id);
echo "</pre>";
```

but $max_id becomes object and output is like that

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 1
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 1
    [type] => 0
)
```

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
 $servername='localhost';
 $username='root';
 $password='';
 $databasename='myDB';
 $con = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$databasename); 
 $result= $con->query("SELECT max(id) from myTable");
 $max_id= mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($max_id);
 echo "</pre>rrr";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much I tried like that now and this works too : $max_id= $con->query('SELECT max(id) from myTable')->fetch_assoc();

Comment: Please consider adding more description to the answer instead of just posting code, it will be more helpful for the future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch result after query.
Please, read the manual here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php

And don't ask questions before reading the official documentation.

Comment: I'm beginner and I learn from my stupid questions :D, thanks a lot @Oleg!